# Flex file upload issue io error #2038 over HTTPS

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, browser, https, filereference

Hi i have a flex file upload application over https it works fine on all IE browsers. 
Recently a client with IE9 reported a complaint that she's not able to upload files.

I can see the error generated is IO Error #2038.

The adobe documentation says 2038 is File I/O Error.This error occurs when an application can't get file size, creation date or modification data using the FileReference API.

Can some one help me point out what could be the issue here.
All i can think of is browser issues like, browser cache, some new configuration in IE9 am unaware of or permission on the client directory.

Help will be much appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Yes i have tried IE9 myself and it works fine on my machine. Also i have a few users using IE9 to upload files.

Comment: I also face same issue. Does ProgressEvent internally calls getFileSize() or creationDate()?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Charles debugging proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), which is must have tool for all Flash/Flex developers, and see the difference in IE8 and IE9. Maybe the problem is in some HTTP headers or something else.

Comment: thanks for this. but for now I have built a seperate HTML file upload for users having problems with flex.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. Later I found out that upload feature doesn't work for latest version of flash player over https. Then I tried sending the upload requests via http instead of https. Now its working fine. Try this, it may help in your case aswell.